# Not able to parse duplicate xml tag values using DocumentBuilder in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm able to parse the XML object if it has a single unique inner tag. But the problem comes when I have two duplicate tags in a parent tag. How can I get both tag values? I'm getting the response as XML string.

Here is my code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(responseXML));
if (is != null) {
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    String errorCode = "";
    NodeList errorDetails = doc.getElementsByTagName("ERROR-LIST");
    if (errorDetails != null) {
        int length = errorDetails.getLength();
        if (length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (errorDetails.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element el = (Element) errorDetails.item(i);
                    if (el.getNodeName().contains("ERROR-LIST")) {
                        NodeList errorCodes = el.getElementsByTagName("ERROR-CODE");
                        for (int j = 0; j < errorCodes.getLength(); j++) {
                            Node errorCode1 = errorCodes.item(j);
                            logger.info(errorCode1.getNodeValue());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            isValidResponse = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The response which I'm getting from server is

```
<DATA><HEADER><RESPONSE-TYPE CODE = "0" DESCRIPTION = "Response Error" />
</HEADER><BODY><ERROR-LIST>
<ERROR-CODE>9000</ERROR-CODE>
<ERROR-CODE>1076</ERROR-CODE>
</ERROR-LIST></BODY></DATA>
```

Im able to get only 9000 error code, how can I catch all error codes which are under error list?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly requesting the first element of the error list:

```
el.getElementsByTagName("ERROR-CODE").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Loop over all the nodes `getElementsByTagName` returns.

```
NodeList errorCodes = el.getElementsByTagName("ERROR-CODE");
for (int j = 0; j < errorCodes.getLength(); j++) {
    String errorCode = errorCodes.item(j).getTextContent();
}
```

Comment: I tried by putting item(i), but still it shows the same. Its because the length ofNodeList errorDetails = doc.getElementsByTagName("ERROR-LIST"); gives as 1.

Comment: @Aliy `i` is the wrong variable to use. That one refers to the amount of ERROR-LIST occurrences, which is 1. See the updated answer.